# Subprocess or import to invoke a script in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-import, python-2.x

I have a script `task.py` that I am trying to invoke. It seems there are two ways to do that. One is to use the `subprocess` API while the other is to use Python's import mechanism.

**task.py**

```
def call_task():
    print("task in progress...")
    return "something"

print("calling task..")
out = call_task()
print("output of the executed task::", out)
```

Now, we have two approaches to invoke the above task.py python script.

**Approach 1**

```
import task as task

print("invoke call-task")
out = task.call_task()
print("output::", out)
```

**Approach 2**

```
import subprocess, shlex, PIPE

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("python task.py"), stdout = PIPE)
out = proc.communicate()
print("output::", out)
```

Although both approaches work, which approach is more pythonic?

Comment: It's not a matter of pythonic or not. It totally depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You're entering asynchronous territory, whilst it doesn't answer your question you may find the following video interesting: [How Does Python Do Multiple Things At Once? (Best Intro Into Asynchronous Programming)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FdeJ2_LDuQ)

Answer (score 4):

Running a separate Python process from Python is frequently an antipattern. There are situations where you specifically *want* two Python instances (for example, if the module you want to use requires its own signal handling etc) but in the absence of factors which force the other choice, `import` is generally vastly preferrable in terms of usability (you get to call the functions inside the package in an order different from its main flow, and have more fine-grained control over the internals) and performance (starting a separate process is almost always a bad idea if you can avoid it).

Answer (score 0):

While "The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes" which executes the code within your task.py,
importing will result in the original process executing your code.

Other than that, it should be identical.

You can read more about it in the [Python Subprocess Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

As i've seen, its rather unusual to execute python code using an extra subprocess.

<strike>It may benefit performance wise but</strike> the more pythonic way would be importing i guess.

Comment: It's not clear how having two processes instead of one would benefit performance. If you are on a multiprocessor system, the GIL generally forces Python to execute all processes on the same CPU anyway. If the scheduler treats all processes equally, starting many processes will give you a bigger share of the total, but many schedulers are smarter than that.

Comment: @tripleee You are right, i was thinking in the wrong direction. It's not performance, it's more like "letting a User/Process wait" for finishing something, that doesn't has to be finished to contiune the actuall process.

Comment: from the performance point of view, which approach will be better.?

Comment: It's depending on what you want do.
If you want raw CPU performance comparison, try it yourself and messure the seconds, it probably won't make much of a difference in ms.
If you have to wait for the subprocess to finish, until you can continue with your main process, you should use import (Which means, you don't use a subprocess). If you can ignore the progress of the subprocess, 
and want to deliver a response as fast as possible, give the subprocess the time consuming work.